# phpmyadmin fail silently with xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using apache and mysql with xampp. Everything in localhost.

But when I try to edit data (`CREATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`) using phpmyadmin, nothing happens. The table or the data hasn't changed and there isn't any error message. The only command working is `SELECT`.

Everything's working fine using the mysql.exe command line. But using the phpmyadmin web interface doesn't work.

Have you an idea about why phpmyadmin doesn't work ?

Comment: did you try it as root user? Maybe it has something to do with your current user permissions

Comment: Yes, I'm logged as root. In my config.inc.php : `/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`

Comment: Do you have any other version of phpmyadmin or mysql or xampp/wamp installed?

Comment: No, I've just installed xampp with apache and mysql.

Comment: Stupid question. Did you opened your browser with "administrator permissions"?

Comment: I've tested, nothing changed...

Comment: Wow bro. I'm sorry, I don't know why is happening... it's very weird.

Comment: I've reinstalled xampp and this still doesn't work. "query processing" is written and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `https://` before your phpmyadmin's url.